# Chrome localStorage persisting across reloads but not restarts

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser, local-storage

This is really weird, but I have a small webpage that uses localStorage to store some user preferences. I have comes across a clients browser, in which localStorage seems to behave exactly like sessionStorage. For example, page works as intended when reloading, opening and closing tabs, but if you fully restart chrome, and then navigate to the page again, localStorage is cleared.

Has anyone seen behaviour like this before?

Comment: incognito mode perhaps?

Comment: It is what I suspected at first, but unfortunately not

Comment: does chrome have the option to clear data on exit? this answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42623706/5053002) made me think

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same behavior (no localStorage after restarting browser).  I had been using CCleaner to 'Automatically clean on closing without notification.'  I changed this option to 'Do not monitor browser.'  That solved the problem for me.

Comment: I also verified this same session-like storage behavior at the following site on my Chrome browser.