# How to Explicitly Request End User to Not Remove Local Storage Data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, local-storage, indexeddb

I am developing application using angularJS. my application require to save data locally. So, I am using HTML5 local storage.

The issue with HTML5 local storage is that when user clears browsing data all the data is being lost and we need this to be avoided. I realize that since the data is stored on the users computer, there is no way to 100% secure the data.

Essentially, is there a way to explicitly tell the browser that this data is special and should not be cleared when data from other sites gets cleared? This would have to be a way that explicitly encourages the user not to delete the local data from this specific site. Or, alternatively, will we need to incorporate a local database. Which local database will be the best option?

Comment: localStorage clearing is primarly a client side option you can't manage, if you need to store datas the only way is a database, you can't exclude that the client is going to clear cache.

Comment: This question deserves more upvotes. The purpose of stack overflow is to help other people learn. This means recognizing and interpreting what people are trying to say instead of antagonizing them for not wording their thoughts as perfectly as someone who already knows the answer to the question they ask.

Answer (score 6):

You can't prevent the user from deleting their data, from their web browser (because it is **their** web browser).

There are no local databases to which that rule does not apply.

If you want to protect against accidental deletion of data: Sync it to a user account on your server.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is [navigator.storage.persist()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/persist). It will not prevent the user from deleting the data (because that would be a major security breach), but it will, essentially, inform the browser that the data must not be deleted because the data cannot be refetched/regenerated from the server. The below code snippet will accomplish what you are after in supporting browsers.

```
"use strict"; // always put this just once at the start of all javascript files
function persistStorage(thenFunc) {
    thenFunc = thenFunc || function(success){
        if (!success) console.error("Failed to request persistant storage!");
    };
    if (
      typeof navigator === "object" && 
      typeof navigator.storage === "object" && 
      typeof navigator.storage.persist === "function"
    ) {
        navigator.storage.persist().then(
            thenFunc.bind(0, true),
            thenFunc.bind(0, false)
        );
    } else {
        thenFunc(false)
    }
}
```

Then, call function `persistStorage`, optionally with a callback that is passed `true` if it succeeds, to persist your storage.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way of preventing a user from deleting local data from the browser (and there should not be one, in my opinion).

If you really want to be sure to preserve your data, you should sync them with your server.

Answer (score 0):

If user clear all the browser data there is no option to retain the local storage. It is up to their choice.

There are storage like webSQL, indexedDB in webkit enabled browsers but if they select to remove site data while clearing the browser the data will loss.

In chorme the checkbox "cookie and site plugin data" in the "clear browsing data menu"  will decide to remove all site data.

Thanks,
MG