# When does browser delete HTML5 Web Storage data?

Tags: html, local-storage, web-storage

I'm using for a project the HTML5 Web Storage, and I need to keep the values forever. These are the functions that I'm using:

```
localStorage.setItem("data_name" , "value") ;
localStorage.getItem("data_name") ;
```

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Chromium browser. Users are not able to do it but, **is there any way with which the browser could delete the data? And if yes, how can I completely avoid this?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 storage stores data persistently means that it does not expire with a session.If you browse away from the site that saved the data or close the browser, you will notice that the data is still there when you open it again or check for it locally.

If you want to prevent end user from deleting HTML5 storage, Refer below link:
[How to Explicitly Request End User to Not Remove Local Storage Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623427/how-to-explicitly-request-end-user-to-not-remove-local-storage-data)